# How to set image of custom cell after selecting another cell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am developing an application in which i have set some images for cells based on some criteria.

After selecting a custom cell i am changing it's image but when i try to select another custom cell.

the image for the previous custom cell remain selected and also the newly selected one.

What i want is that the image of previously selected custom cell should be set to default image which 
i have given initially.

Kindly help m with this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Put your criteria in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and everytime you update your selected cell probably in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` make a `[self.tableView reloadData]` that makes the tableView to reload the data and call it's delegate methods again.
Hope that helps.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if(requirementMet){ // if your criteria where met
      cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"specialImage.png"];
    } else{
      cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultCellImage.png"];
    }

 return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //do your select things here
  [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Can u explain with an example ?