# How to add a content view on UITAbleViewCell when a row is selected?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uitableview

I'm trying to add a button when a row is selected in `UITableView` and also remove it when row is tapped second time, i don't want custom `UITableViewCell`.

Any suggestion or sample code will be appreciated.

code i've tried:
in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**  method

```
if(cell.selected == YES){

                UITextField* numOfBottles =[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240,9.0f,50, 25)];
                numOfBottles.tag = indexPath.row;

                [numOfBottles setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
                [numOfBottles setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                [numOfBottles setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                [numOfBottles setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
                [numOfBottles setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_dropdown_normal.png"]];
                [numOfBottles setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f]];
                [numOfBottles setDelegate:self];

                NSString* quantity = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[subtotalObj.qtyArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row - 1)]];

                [numOfBottles setText:quantity];
                [numOfBottles setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
                [numOfBottles setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                numOfBottles.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
               // numOfBottles.tag = indexPath.row;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:numOfBottles];
                [numOfBottles release];
            }
```

and in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

But still button(textfield with background image) is not rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to use a UITableViewCell subclass.
But you can use my answer on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881376/how-to-set-image-of-custom-cell-after-selecting-another-cell/12881543#12881543) to make your TableView rerender and place a button in your cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if(indexPath.row == selectedRow){ // if your criteria where met
      //add your button
    }

     return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //do your select things here
  selectedRow = indexPath.row; //where selectedRow is a class variable
  [self.tableView reloadData]; // rerenders the tableview

}
```

Comment: I would recommend you to give us a Code snippet what you have tried.

Comment: I added a variable, this is the fastest way I think. `cell.selected` only works in a UITableViewCell subclass

Answer (score 0):

There's `UITableView` delegate, `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` implement it, where you'll get the row which user tapped, get the current `cell`using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you need to pass `NSIndexPath` using the `section` and `row`. Now check if `cell.contentView subviews` has `UIButton` which you want? If yes, perform `removeFromSuperView` else `addSubView`. If you `cell` have already filled with `UIButton`s you can give `unique` tag to distinguish them.

Answer (score 0):

Use these delegates

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  //Create reference of button with tag 999
  cell.contentView addSubView:yourButtonReference]
  [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

}

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *btnAdded = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:999];
    if(btnAdded){
      [btnAdded removeFromSuperView];
      [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
}
```