# how to add a custom view in the selected row in UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am new at programming and struggling in this.
how to add a custom view in the selected row in UITableView?

All other rows should not be affected. The new view should appear in place of the row clicked. The view can have a bigger size.
Thanks.

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
use this method to change the size of the cell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add new view in rowDidSelect Delegate method,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 100.0f, 30.0f)];
[myView setTag:-1];

[cell addSubview:myView];

}
```

Implement DidDeselectRowatindexpath also as given

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIView *myView = [cell viewWithTag:-1];

[myView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: using the above code, when i click some other row, the subview appears on previously clicked row. why is that?

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);  //  

        str=[appdelegate.name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];     //DetailViewController is your view

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: sorry it's my mistake i forget.

Answer (score 0):

I havn't tried this but it may work let me know if it works.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexpath];

       [cell.contentView addSubView: yourviewObject];

       cell.bounds.size.height = yourViewObject.bounds.size.height + 10.0;


}
```

Answer (score -1):

see this for add custom view in selected row of uitableview

[How to add a content view on UITAbleViewCell when a row is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953226/how-to-add-a-content-view-on-uitableviewcell-when-a-row-is-selected)